# Dúvida cast com ponteiro

Tags: c, variáveis

```
 while( ++idx <= fp_size)
 {  
     byte current = buff[idx];
     int integer = 0 ; 
     short shortint = 0 ; 

     if(idx < fp_size - 3)
         integer = *((int *))&buff[idx];
 }
```

Que tipo de cast é este `*((int *))`?   variável `integer` é  do tipo `int` é `buff unsigned char`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O cast é apenas o `(int *)`. O resto é referência e dereferência.

O que acontece nessa linha é o seguinte:

Primeiro, é pego o endereço de um elemento do vetor `buff`: `&buff[idx]`. Se `buff` é do tipo `unsigned char`, será retornado um `unsigned char *`.

Feito isso, é realizado um cast de `unsigned char*` para `int*`: `(int *)`.

Finalmente, é feita uma derreferência em `*`, retornando um `int`.

A variável `int` irá conter os seguintes valores em seus bytes:

```
buff[idx]
buff[idx + 1]
buff[idx + 2]
buff[idx + 3]
```

Isso se a *endianness* da sua máquina for *little endiann*. Se for *big endiann*, será a ordem inversa.